# Code generator for spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have been working in php frameworks like symfony where they have code generators or CLI tools to generate codes like forms, models. In ORM like propel, doctrine, they have cli tools to generate all the DBA models of database tables.

Are there any such code generators in spring mvc framework and Hibernate framework ? I am working windows platform

Comment: try rational , RAD has a good code gen , also Jude from sourceforge.net

Comment: RAD is also really cheap...not!

Answer (score 5):

Please consider using [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo).

Comment: Roo is nice, just be prepared for heavy reliance on AOP.

Answer (score 4):

You might try **Telosys Tools** (http://www.telosys.org),
this simple code generator is very easy to use.

- Eclipse plugin : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools
- VSCode Plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=telosysteam.telosys

It provides a set of templates to generate the JPA/Hibernates entities
You can also generate a fully operational web app with Spring MVC
or other, see the tuto : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/

Comment: Telosys is great because you can create your own templates or customize existing templates (it’s not a “black box”). So you can generate exactly what you want and obtain really clean code.

Answer (score 0):

jHipster can do that.

JHipster is a free and open-source application generator used to quickly develop modern web applications and Microservices using Angular or React (JavaScript library) and the Spring Framework.

https://www.jhipster.tech/

https://www.jhipster.tech/tech-stack/